# Why am I not getting a Boolean?

Tags: python, operators, boolean-expression

```
>>> 'a' in 'aeiou' or 'steve'
True
>>> 'S' in 'Sam' and 'Steve'
'Steve'
>>> 'a' in 'aeiou' and 'steve'
'steve'
>>> 's' in 'aeiou' or 'AEIOU'
'AEIOU'
```

I was working on a class for some students and was surprised by the last three outputs.  I was expecting a boolean. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: maybe that link will help http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

Comment: It's the documented behavior of these 'and' and 'or' operators; they implement short-circuit evaluation and return the first value (left-to-right) which causes the short circuit.  So 1 and "" returns 1 while '' or 'that' returns 'that', for example.

Answer (score 5):

**Boolean Operations**

1. **or**

x or y | if x is false, then y, else x

Demo

```
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> 0 or 0
0
```

2. **and**

x and y | if x is false, then x, else y

Demo

```
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> 1 and 0
0
>>> 1 and 1
1
>>>
```

**Note:**
 These only evaluate their second argument if needed for their outcome.

---

1. **in**

This will return `True` when condition is satisfy otherwise `False`.

Demo:

```
>>> "a" in "abc"
True
>>> "a" in "xyz"
False
>>>
```

---

**Now about our statement:**

**1.** As `'a' in 'aeiou'` return `True` value and we are performing `or` operation, so this will return `True` because First(Left) value of expression is `True`.

Demo:

```
>>> 'a' in 'aeiou'
True
>>> 'a' in 'aeiou' or 'steve'
True
>>>
```

**2.** As `'S' in 'Sam'` return `True` and we are performing `and` operation, So this will return second value from the expression.

Demo:

```
>>> 'S' in 'Sam'
True
>>> 'S' in 'Sam' and 'Steve'
'Steve'
>>>
```

**3.** Same as second statement.

**4.** As `'s' in 'aeiou'` return `False` and we are performing `or` operation, So this will return second value from the expression.

Demo:

```
>>> 's' in 'aeiou'
False
>>> 's' in 'aeiou' or 'AEIOU'
'AEIOU'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your expressions are evaluated like this

```
>>> ('a' in 'aeiou') or ('steve')
True
>>> ('S' in 'Sam') and ('Steve')
'Steve'
>>> ('a' in 'aeiou') and ('steve')
'steve'
>>> ('s' in 'aeiou') or ('AEIOU')
'AEIOU'
```

The `or` and `and` operators, evaluate the expressions and return the result of the evaluation.

So, `or` will first evaluate the LHSE (Left Hand Side Expression) and if it is Truthy (see below), it will return the evaluated result immediately (short-circuiting). Only if it is Falsy (see below), it will evaluate and return the the result of RHSE.

Similarly, `and` will evaluate the LHSE and if it is Falsy it will return the value immediately otherwise it will return the result of evaluation of the RHSE.

**Truthy and Falsy**

Quoting the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

So, in the first case, `('a' in 'aeiou')` is `True`, so it returns `True` immediately.

In the second case, `('S' in 'Sam')` is `False`, so it returns the result of evaluating `('Steve')` which is `Steve` only.

In the third case, `('a' in 'aeiou')` is `True`, and so it returns the result of evaluating `('steve')` which is `steve` only.

In the last case, `('s' in 'aeiou')` is `False`, so it returns the result of evaluating `('AEIOU')` which is `AEIOU` only.

Apart from this, you can get to know if your expressions are actually Truthy or Falsy with the [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) function, like this

```
>>> bool('a' in 'aeiou' or 'steve')
True
>>> bool('S' in 'Sam' and 'Steve')
True
>>> bool('a' in 'aeiou' and 'steve')
True
>>> bool('s' in 'aeiou' or 'AEIOU')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
'a' in somestring or 'steve'
```

is interpreted as:

```
('a' in somestring) or 'steve'
```

which will either give you `True` or `'steve'`, depending on whether `a` is in `somestring`. It is for `'aeiou'` but not for `'xyzzy'`:

```
>>> 'a' in 'aeiou' or 'steve'
True
>>> 'a' in 'xyzzy' or 'steve'
'steve'
```

If you want to check if the letter is in either word, use:

```
('a' in 'aeiou') or ('a' in 'steve')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page explains it http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html. You're running into interesting BODMAS rules and what happens when you apply logical operations to a bool and a string (strings evaluate to true - https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Both the operation and the order matter:

- 's' and False = False # False and x is always False
- False and 's' = False
- 's' or False  = s # False or x is always x
- False or 's'  = s
- 's' and True  = True # !false and True = the last of the 2
- True and 's'  = s
- 's' or True   = s # !false or True = the last of the 2
- True or 's'   = True
- 's' and 'a'   = a # !false and !false = the last of the 2
- 's' or 'a'    = s

Answer (score 0):

In Python

- or: from left to right if value is boolean if value is true return this or if value is all false return last item.
  example: False or 3 return 3, 4 or 3 return 3, '' or False or - 1 return -1.
- and: evaluate from left to right and return last value != False or first value if value is False.

example:

1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 return 5: because 1,2,3,4,5 all is not False then return last value is 5.

-1 and 3 and 4 return 4; -1 is not False; 3,4 is not False too then return the last. Remember that negative value is not False :D.
   0 and 3 return 0. 0 is False then return False

> ```
> >>> 'a' in 'aeiou' or 'steve'
> True
> ```

'a' in 'aeiou' is not False ; 'steve' is not False 
In or operator return first value is not False then this is 'a' in 'aeiou' is True.

> ```
> >>> 'S' in 'Sam' and 'Steve'
> 'Steve'
> ```
>
> 'S' in 'Sam' is True; 'Steve' is not False
>   In and operator return last value is not False this is 'Steve' then resule is 'Steve'
>
> ```
> >>> 'a' in 'aeiou' and 'steve'
> 'steve'
> ```

'a' in 'aeiou' is True, 'steve' is not False
then return last value is not False is 'steve'

> ```
> >>> 's' in 'aeiou' or 'AEIOU'
> 'AEIOU'
> ```

's' in 'aeiou' is False ; 'AEIOU' is not False
then return first value is not False is 'AEIOU'

More in that link: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html